# Hosting a Flask Application in lighttpd using fastcgi

Tags: python, flask, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am having alot of problems trying to get a simple web service created using the Flask python framework hosted in lighttpd using fastcgi.

I completed all the configuration in the lighttpd.conf and the conf.d/fastcgi.conf files.

However, what happens when I restart the lighttpd server it fails to stop:

I run the following command

```
lighttpd -f topic_service.fcgi
```

and I get

```
topic_service.fcgi line: 2 pos: 29 parser failed somehow near here: flup.server.fcgi
```

I then deleted all the content of the .fcgi file and I got the following error back when running the same command:

```
2012-07-18 02:42:51: (configfile.c.1227) a default document-root has to be set  
2012-07-18 02:42:51: (server.c.627) setting default values failed
```

I set the server.document root in the configuration file which looks like this but it does not help:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "75.101.128.251/topic_service" {
        server.document-root = "/home/ec2-user/topic_service"
        fastcgi.server = (
                "/topic_service.fcgi" =>
                ((
                        "socket" => "/tmp/topic_service-fcgi.sock",
                        "bin-path" => "/home/ec2-user/topic_service/topic_service.fcgi",
                        "check-local" => "disable",
                        "max-procs" => 1
                ))
        )
        url.rewrite-once = (
                "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
                "^(/.*)$" => "/topic_service.fcgi$1")
    }
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set generic `server.document-root` (read: not within any conditionals!). You can overwrite it within the if statements as required.

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/server_document-rootdetails